# Getting unresolved symbols after using -nostdlib?

Tags: c++builder, ghc

After adding  this flag  **-nostdlib** ,  During compilation of code , i am getting error as highlighted in bold

**_d_itod   from Analogs.o**

**_d_mul   from Analogs.o**

**_d_sub   from Analogs.o**

**_d_dtof  from Analogs.o**

**_f_ftod  from Analogs.o**

**_d_div   from Analogs.o**

i am unable to figure out why these errors are coming, if i remove this library my software code is building without giving any error.

can some help me out in fixing this issue.

Answer (score 3):

`-nostdlib` is not a library, it's an indication to the compiler/linker that it shouldn't include the standard library in your executable.

If you *need* stuff from the standard library, you shouldn't use this flag.

If you don't think they should be used, you need to find out what's using them, and stop it.

Based on the errors, `Analogs.o` (which *probably* comes from `Analogs.cpp`) is requesting those functions. If you have control over that code, you can find another way for it to achieve its ends, *without* those functions.

Or, whether you have control of it or not, you can provide the functions yourself rather than depending on the standard libraries.

Comment: thanks for replying, but will you please tell me , if i want to use this flag -nostdlib , how would i remove these errors. i am unable to figure it out why these unresolved symbols are comming..

Comment: @Deadlock that's like asking "if I want to not use a screwdriver, how should I get this screw in?".

Comment: @Deadlock: added some more meat to the answer, hopefully covering your query.